# Javascript interval loop stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a Javascript interval loop written that just sticks on the running part unless the buttons i made to stop it are clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JScript Loop</title>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  window.onload=function(){
  var stop = false;
  var go = false;
  var obj = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
      stop = true;
  });
  var obj = document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function () {
      stop = false;
  });

  var interval;

  function loop() {
      var result = document.getElementById("result");
      var layout = document.getElementById("layout");

      if (!stop) {
          result.innerHTML = "Running...";      
      } else {
          result.innerHTML = "Stopped...";
      }
  }
  interval = setInterval(loop, 500);


      var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
      do{
      var mydata = JSON.parse(data);    
        result2.innerHTML = mydata[0].name;
      }while(stop);


  }//]]> 

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="result"></p>
  <button id="btn">Stop</button>
  <button id="btn2">Start</button>
  <p id="result2"></p>
  </body>

  </html>
```

What I was hoping to accomplish is that when the `mydata[0].name` is updated within the `data.json`. file that it will issue the stop to become false and reload the page.

Basically this whole code is to load a variable from a data file for an iframe source, and so that if the data file hasn't changed, it keeps the same `src` for the iframe, but if that `mydata[0].name` variable changes, the page will reload and load the new `src` into the iframe.

I've been stuck on this for the past few hours and just can't put it together on what I need to use to fix it.

UPDATE 9/25/2015 Code changes

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
function loadChirp(){ //start function
var ThePath;
   $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/data.json", 
        function(data){
            var CurPath = data.path;
            var ChkPath = data.path;
            display('Cur Path is: ' + CurPath);
        }); 
} //end function 

function tick(CurPath, ChkPath) {
    var CurPath = CurPath;  
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/data.json", 
        function(data2){
            display('Cur Path is: ' + CurPath);
            var ChkPath = data2.path;
            if(ChkPath !== CurPath) {
                var ChkPath = data2.path;
                var CurPath = data2.path;
                display('ChkPath is: ' + ChkPath);
            }

        });
}       
function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var CurPath;
var ThePath;
//DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION
loadChirp();
setInterval(tick, 30000); // Set for 1 Minute to use 1 hour its 3600000
}); 
//DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION 

</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes it has an infinite loop because i always want it checking for a change based on the time interval.

Answer (score 0):

The `data.json` file will only load once when page loads.

It will not refresh itself within the lifecycle of the page.
Therefore `var mydata = JSON.parse(data);` will always be the same data pulled from memory, not from server

If you are looking for updates to that file you need to use ajax to retrieve the data again and check it in ajax completion callback.

As for the interval stopping, there is nothing in your code that would make it stop except for clicking the button.

`while(stop)` will create an infinite loop race condition. Get rid of that!

Any further assistance is difficult because it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I guess if i full explain what i'm trying to accomplish:

To Explain it we have a vehicle with a layout ID assigned in a data file that is hosted in our dropbox folder. What i basically am trying to do is refresh the layout path if the layout ID has changed in that file. So i'm trying to make it monitor that file for a variable change to the layout ID.

Comment: We already have the backend process where the layout ID is generated and updates that data.json file on the fly for us but i need this part of the application to check if it changes and then reload the page using the new variables but don't want it to reload unless that layout ID has changed.

Comment: ok well you need to use ajax or websockets to check updates. The browser only loads what it is told to, when it is asked for

Comment: I've now switched it to using AJAX to load and check the file in a loop, but i keep getting a CurPath is undefined and the if statement inside the tick function is looping. I'm trying to figure out how to make the tick loop run on the interval time set and check if the path in the data.son file has changed. If it has changed then set the CurPath to that and refresh the page to reload my iframe which i haven't loaded into this code yet until i can figure out how to do this check.

Comment: I have no idea what `cuurPath` is. Suggest you start a new question with your code and accept this one if it helped you

Comment: context of question changes based on that new code since you have a different problem now. Start a new question. WHen properly structured it will ge reviewed much quicker than updates to this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790423/ajax-check-data-file-for-changes-and-display-getting-undefined-curpath-in-tick